# Swiper JS return to first slide

Tags: slider, swiper.js

I have slider with swiper js, how it can return to first slide when we click Next Button on end of slide ?

http://idangero.us

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `loop` parameter. For example:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-header', {
  loop: true, //this should allow the last next button to return to the beginning
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version 7.4.0 in swiper.js has a "rewind" parameter that returns the slider to the beginning if the user scrolled to the last slide and clicked "next".

Docs: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-rewind

Answer (score 0):

i made function like this:
.swiper-next is: navigation - nextEl

```
var changed = false;
$(".swiper-next").on('click', function () {
    if (changed === true) {
        changed = false;
        faqSwiper.slideTo(0);
    }
    if (faqSwiper.isEnd) changed = true;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use "click" event from Swiper API.

Note: **setTimeout** is needed to correctly determine slide index

```
const swiper_instance = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // ...
});

swiper_instance.on('click', function (swiper, event) {
    const is_next_click = event.target === swiper.navigation.nextEl,
        is_prev_click = event.target === swiper.navigation.prevEl,
        is_end = this.isEnd,
        is_beginning = this.isBeginning;

    // slide to begin
    if (is_next_click && is_end) {
        setTimeout(() => swiper.slideTo(0))
    }

    // slide to end
    if (is_prev_click && is_beginning) {
        setTimeout(() => swiper.slideTo(swiper.slides.length))
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.